# How to use generics in companion object

Tags: generics, kotlin

I'd like to use generics in *companion object* in this way:

```
class Foo<T> {
    /* ... */
    companion object {
        fun foo(args: List<T>) {
            /* ... */
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the code above raise `Unresolved reference: T` error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You either need to declare the generic like so

```
fun <T> foo(args: List<T>) { ... }
```

or, if you don't care about the type, you can use a star projection

```
fun foo(args: List<*>) { ... }
```

Comment: i have declared in class name but.. have declare again into companion object

Comment: The companion object (like any object) can't be generic. Remember, the companion object is for the class itself, not for an instance of the class.

Comment: @ruckus also for class I can't define a class (first) that inherits abstract class that has companion that can use (first) class if I define my abstract class generic type as `abstract class AbstractClass <T: AbstractClass<T>>`. So I still can't return (first) class type using companion in abstract

Answer (score 3):

### Companion object is shared

Generic type parameters of the class are not allowed inside the companion objects. The reason is that a single `companion object` is shared across all the instances of that class. This is true also for the different parameterized types of the same class. So, for example, the `companion object` is the same for whether it is a `Foo<String>` or a `Foo<Int>`. In other words, the `T` of the enclosing class cannot take different forms `String` or `Int` inside the `companion object`.

The type parameters can only be used with the member functions and member properties of the class.

---

### Closest possible solution

You can define a separate type parameter for the function inside the companion object:

```
class Foo<T> {
    /* ... */
    companion object {
        fun <T> foo(args: List<T>) {
            /* ... */
        }
    }
}
```

The `T` of `Foo` and `T` of `foo()` are independent in this case and need to be instantiated separately:

```
val instance = Foo<String>()
Foo.foo(listOf<String>())
```

---

That's it! Hope that helps understanding the concept.